# R - dividing a huge dataframe of latitude/longitude points into groups according to location

Tags: r, optimization

I am new at R, but I hear that it is really a bad idea to use `for` loops. I have working code using them, but I would like to improve it because it's extremely slow with big data. I already have a few ideas how to improve the algorithm, but what I don't know is how to vectorize this, or do it without `for` loops.

I am simply grouping lat/lng points into a circles with radius as parameter.

An example output of the function(only fills the values in the circle_id column), radius was set to 100 meters:

```
[1] "Locations: "
   latitude  longitude sensor_time sensor_time2         circle_id
   48.15144  17.07569  1447149703  2015-11-10 11:01:43         1
   48.15404  17.07452  1447149743  2015-11-10 11:02:23         2
   48.15277  17.07514  1447149762  2015-11-10 11:02:42         3
   48.15208  17.07538  1447149771  2015-11-10 11:02:51         1
   48.15461  17.07560  1447149773  2015-11-10 11:02:53         4
   48.15139  17.07562  1447149811  2015-11-10 11:03:31         1
   48.15446  17.07517  1447149866  2015-11-10 11:04:26         2
   48.15266  17.07330  1447149993  2015-11-10 11:06:33         5
```

So I have 2 for loops, loop1 goes through every line and loop2 goes through every previous circle_id's and checks if current location from loop1 is within the radius of existing circles from loop2. The centre of each circle_id is the first location found outside all previous one's radius.

Here's the code:

```
init_circles = function(datfr, radius) {
  cnt = 1
  datfr$circle_id[1] = 1
  longitude = datfr$longitude[1]
  latitude = datfr$latitude[1]
  circle_id = datfr$circle_id[1]
  datfr2 <- data.frame(longitude, latitude, circle_id)

  for (i in 2:NROW(datfr)) {
      for (j in 1:NROW(datfr2)) {
        tmp = distHaversine(c(datfr$longitude[i],datfr$latitude[i]) ,c(datfr2$longitude[j],datfr2$latitude[j]))
        if (tmp < radius){
          datfr$circle_id[i] = datfr2$circle_id[j]
          break
        }
      }
      if (datfr$circle_id[i]<1){
        cnt = cnt +1
        datfr$circle_id[i] = cnt
        datfr2[nrow(datfr2)+1,] = c(datfr$longitude[i],datfr$latitude[i],datfr$circle_id[i])
      }
  }
  return(datfr)
}
```

**datfr** is the input dataframe without circle_id's set, and **datfr2** is a temporary dataframe containing already existing circles.

EDIT: here is a visual output:
[image]

You can see what those circles are used for, the upper red circle has 21 other locations that fit within its radius (21 + 1 original = 22)

Thank you so much for helping,
Alena

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've assumed we have a data frame `circles` with the center and radius of each circle and that the sample data posted in your question is in a data frame called `dat`. The code below vectorizes the calculation of distance and uses `lapply` to calculate the distance of each point from the center of each circle and to determine if each point is inside the radius of that circle.

```
library(geosphere)

# We'll check the distance of each data point from the center of each 
#  of these circles
circles = data.frame(ID=1:2, lon=c(17.074, 17.076), lat=c(48.1513, 48.15142), 
                     radius=c(180,190))

datNew = lapply(1:nrow(circles), function(i) {

  df = dat

  df$dist = distHaversine(df[,c("longitude", "latitude")], 
                          circles[rep(i,nrow(df)), c('lon','lat')])

  df$in_circle = ifelse(df$dist <= circles[i, "radius"], "Yes", "No")

  df$circle_id = circles[i, "ID"]

  df

})

datNew = do.call(rbind, datNew)

datNew
```

> ```
>    latitude longitude sensor_time sensor_time2    time3      dist in_circle circle_id
> 1  48.15144  17.07569  1447149703   2015-11-10 11:01:43 126.47756       Yes         1
> 2  48.15404  17.07452  1447149743   2015-11-10 11:02:23 307.45048        No         1
> 3  48.15277  17.07514  1447149762   2015-11-10 11:02:42 184.24465        No         1
> 4  48.15208  17.07538  1447149771   2015-11-10 11:02:51 134.32601       Yes         1
> 5  48.15461  17.07560  1447149773   2015-11-10 11:02:53 387.15358        No         1
> 6  48.15139  17.07562  1447149811   2015-11-10 11:03:31 120.73138       Yes         1
> 7  48.15446  17.07517  1447149866   2015-11-10 11:04:26 362.34236        No         1
> 8  48.15266  17.07330  1447149993   2015-11-10 11:06:33 160.07179       Yes         1
> 9  48.15144  17.07569  1447149703   2015-11-10 11:01:43  23.13059       Yes         2
> 10 48.15404  17.07452  1447149743   2015-11-10 11:02:23 311.68096        No         2
> 11 48.15277  17.07514  1447149762   2015-11-10 11:02:42 163.29068       Yes         2
> 12 48.15208  17.07538  1447149771   2015-11-10 11:02:51  86.70762       Yes         2
> 13 48.15461  17.07560  1447149773   2015-11-10 11:02:53 356.34955        No         2
> 14 48.15139  17.07562  1447149811   2015-11-10 11:03:31  28.41890       Yes         2
> 15 48.15446  17.07517  1447149866   2015-11-10 11:04:26 343.97933        No         2
> 16 48.15266  17.07330  1447149993   2015-11-10 11:06:33 243.44024        No         2
> ```

So we now have a data frame telling us whether each point is inside a given circle. The data frame is in long format, meaning that there are `n` rows for each point in the original data frame `dat`, where `n` is the number of rows in the `circles` data frame. From here, you can do further processing, such as just keeping one row for each point that's in multiple circles, etc.

Here's an example. We'll return a data frame listing which circles a point is inside of, or return "None" if the point is not inside any circle:

```
library(dplyr)

datNew %>%
  group_by(latitude, longitude) %>% 
  summarise(in_which_circles = if(any(in_circle=="Yes")) paste(circle_id[in_circle=="Yes"], collapse=",") else "None")
```

> ```
>   latitude longitude in_which_circles
>      <dbl>     <dbl>            <chr>
> 1 48.15139  17.07562              1,2
> 2 48.15144  17.07569              1,2
> 3 48.15208  17.07538              1,2
> 4 48.15266  17.07330                1
> 5 48.15277  17.07514                2
> 6 48.15404  17.07452             None
> 7 48.15446  17.07517             None
> 8 48.15461  17.07560             None
> ```

Comment: http://i67.tinypic.com/vgnc0o.png here you can see what those circles are used for, the upper red circle has 21 other locations that fit within its radius (21 + 1 original = 22)

Comment: If I understand your picture then I just need a data frame with the lat and long of the center of each circle and the radius of each circle, and then I calculate the distance of each point in your sample data from the center of each circle and see whether it falls within the radius. But I still don't understand what you want the output to be. What if a given point is inside more than one circle?

Comment: From what I understand, this makes sense and should be sufficient enough for the visual output i want to accomplish. I will have to try to be sure however :)

Comment: if it is inside two circles, it will just keep the id from first one, or second, doesnt matter... i am not going in such detail here. It can even be square, not circle if that's easier. The only rule is that all data is divided into some groups with radius and every location gets assigned to only one group.

the circle_id's are created while algorithm is running, we don't know beforehand which point will be selected as new location group

Comment: I tried to make your previous answer work and it seems great. but as the haversine function only returns distance in meters, can it happen that it will put two points in the same group that have the same distance from first recorded location BUT different angle?

Comment: Yes. If you want to distinguish by angle in addition to radius, you'd need to calculate direction as well and group by that.

Comment: could you please show an example how to use `cut` and `seq` on such a group, this seems to be really complicated

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, usng a **for** loop is not necessary a bad idea, and sometimes I prefer using a loop to make my code cleaner rather than nested **apply**.

However in your case, you could try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# I only load the coordinate for now
df <- tibble(latitude  = c(48.15144, 48.15404, 48.15277, 48.15208, 48.15461, 48.15139, 48.15446, 48.15266),
             longitude = c(17.07569, 17.07452, 17.07514, 17.07538, 17.07560, 17.07562, 17.07517, 17.07330))

df %>% 
  unite(coord, latitude, longitude, sep = ", ") %>% 
  mutate(coord2 = coord) %>% 
  expand(coord, coord2) %>% 
  mutate(coord = map(coord, function(x) {xx <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))); tibble(lat = xx[1], lon = xx[2])})) %>% 
  mutate(coord2 = map(coord2, function(x) {xx <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))); tibble(lat2 = xx[1], lon2 = xx[2])})) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dist = distHaversine(c(lon, lat), c(lon2, lat2))) %>% 
  group_by(lat, lon) %>% 
  mutate(group = 1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(dist < 100) %>% 
  group_by(lat, lon) %>% 
  summarise(group = min(group))
```

You end up with different ideas for the coordinates. As is however, the order of your data is lost.